# use php variables for awk regex commands

Tags: php, regex, awk

trying to implement autosuggest using php. autosuggest list generated using awk

```
    $input= $_GET["term"];
   $suggest=array();
   exec('awk \'BEGIN{FS=","}/.$input./{print $2,"-cost-",$1}\' 3.txt',$suggest);
   echo json_encode($suggest)
```

in place of $input to test autosuggest i was using a charachrecter eg.A, works fine. however i am not able to take a dynamic character as an input to awk. some thing wrong with .$input. cant figure out how to write the escape characters

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that substituting GET parameters into shell commands unsanitized is a good idea? If I go to your website and pass `term=';rm -Rf / #`, you are unlikely to like the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn

```
exec('awk \'BEGIN{FS=","}/.$input./{print $2,"-cost-",$1}\' 3.txt',$suggest);
```

Into:

```
exec('awk \'BEGIN{FS=","}/'.$input.'/{print $2,"-cost-",$1}\' 3.txt',$suggest);
```

You forgot to terminate the first `'`, which is required, since you can't expand variables within single quoted strings.

Side note: As pointed out in the comments, you might want to think twice about blindly accepting `GET` parameters as shell commands, without some sort of security checking. Users can and will quickly find a way to exploit that flaw...

Comment: I think a better solution would be to `putenv("input=$input")` before the exec call and fish the variable out of the environment with `exec('awk -F, -v input="$input" \'$0 ~ input { print $2, "-cost-", $1 }\' 3.txt', $suggest)` or, better yet, use `proc_open` to do the same thing. Disclaimer: Code untested, rusty php-fu.

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply. @Wintermute could you please provide some key words as to learn more about security checking

Comment: @user1869714 yes I would tend to agree with Wintermute's comment. Since I am pretty rusty with PHP as well, I will refrain from trying to mangle the answer with any further suggestions from me, but do look into that.

Comment: I think it'd be possible to use `exec('awk -F, -v input=' . escapeshellarg($input) . ' \'$0 ~ input { print $2, "-cost-", $1 }\' 3.txt', $suggest);`, come to think of it again. [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) to `escapeshellarg` docs. [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) is a good resource, with relevant articles on [code injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Code_Injection) and [command injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_Injection). That might serve as a starting point.